# Decode SHA256 to string

Tags: c#, hash, sha256

How can I decode SHA256 in c#?
I tested an online SHA256 Decrypt website and it worked.
Is it possible in c#?

https://10015.io/tools/sha256-encrypt-decrypt

Comment: it works for a some common words, but fails more often then not for everything else.  *Is it possible in c#?* - it's certainly possible to replicate what the website is doing.

Comment: @JamieRees No. I checked that question but I find the SHA256 Decrypt website. So I asked this question to find a way use in c#

Comment: @jps I used SHA256 for store four-digit numbers. I encrypt and decrypt many four-digit numbers and it worked.

Comment: @MrAbdoli sure, you can easily write a loop that tries all combinations of 1 to 4 digit numbers and find a result quickly. Probably so quick that no one will notice that you're just trying all combinations.  Just a matter of computing power. Try with some more digits and a broader range of characters....

Answer (score 1):

On the website we can read

```
SHA256 is a hashing algorithm. There is no direct method for SHA256 decryption. SHA256 is decrypted by using Trial & Error methodology. It may take some time if either the text that will be decrypted or the character set that will be used for decryption is long.
```

Basically a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (such as sha256) is irreversible. You **cannot** retrieve the inputs given a hash (that's why it's widely used for security purposes).

In order to perform a "decryption", you only have one way to go : guess and check. That what the website does `[...] SHA256 is decrypted by using Trial & Error methodology [..]`.

Comment: So the website uses the only way (guessing and checking)?

Comment: @MrAbdoli exactly